# Wordpress, delay JS after template render

Tags: javascript, wordpress, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating, underscores-wp

I have some `<script type="text/template">...</script>` in a Wordpress website which is new to me and found out it is related to Underscore.js (?). However I am not familiar with it.

How can I execute a javascript function after the rendering of that (or all the) template, after the dom has been updated and elements can be found using `document.querySelector('...')`?

I tried the usual

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {...})
jQuery(document).ready(function() {...})
```

but they execute too early when the template was not yet rendered in the page.

Comment: Based on just the question text, Underscore may or may not play a role in this. In any case, though, Underscore does not decide when the template will be rendered, because Underscore is purely a utility toolkit (which happen to have a render function). There is probably a solution to your problem, but I'd need to see your project setup to see what's going on. Ideally, please add a link to a public repository of your source code.

Comment: @Julian Thanks for taking commenting. I ended up doing a work around using MutationObserver. By the lack of answers I suspect this to be specific to the template I am using (poorly documentend). Anyway if someone is facing this problem and wants a working solutions do the following:
In `callback()` you check if the element is present, if so do your business.

1) Check if your element is in the DOM. If it is then `callback()`, if not do number 2.

2) Setup a `const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)`

3) `observer.observe(someParentElement, { subtree: true, childList: true })`